# Windows 7 Themes for Lubuntu/LXDE

Tags: lubuntu, windows-7, themes, lxde

Does anyone know of any LXDE themes that look like Windows? I want it to be able to fool someone into thinking that it's actually Windows.

Comment: Have you considered using using Windows? It's where the interface you're looking for works best.

Comment: @CelticWarrior The point is simply NOT to use Windows. It's slow, costs money and I can't put it on thumb-sticks. I'm looking for something like Tails' "Stealth Mode" or whatever they call it now.

Comment: Linux is NOT a free replacement for Windows. It's different. Do not try to make like the other, especially by trying to emulate the look&feel of an **outdated** UI.

Comment: I know it's not. I'm not trying to emulate a Window's theme because I CAN'T afford it, I'm trying to emulate it so people don't bother me and ask "Woah! What is that!?". It seems unlikely, but it happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you doing this on a school computer that's supposed to be running Windows? It sounds an awful lot like you are trying to hide something. In that case, I highly advice against doing so.

Regardless, yes and no- There are plenty of Windows icon packs and general gnome-themes that you can compile into a theme.

However, if you really want to emulate the function, size of taskbar, etc. of Windows, you would have to make your own desktop environment.

Have fun doing that, if you want to.

Comment: Is there any way how I can compile all of these into a theme?

Comment: The easiest way is to go to /usr/share/themes, and edit existing themes by replacing pictures. Be sure when replacing icons and images you use images that are the same resolution and are of similar design. Upvote if this helped.